# How to DROP database with different case in the name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to drop this kind of database name in MariaDB :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> DROP DATABASE `db_IRP_rec` ;
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'db_irp_rec'; database doesn't exist
```

It seems mysql doesn't give a care of the case in the name of the database same if we put the name between `` ` ` ``

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have a database named like that? Does `SHOW DATABASES` list your database the way you believe it should be listed? AFAIK, database names are stored on disk in lowercase and name comparisons are case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check whether the database exists or not.

```
MariaDB> show databases;
```

If DB exists and you cannot delete on MySQL prompt, you can clean the DB at data directory.

```
MariaDB>  show variables where Variable_name ='datadir';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

In my case, datas are stored under `/var/lib/mysql`.

We can find a folder with the same name as the database.

just remove or move to some other path.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/<databaseName>
```

Comment: Hi, The command `show variables where Variable_name ='datadir';` return empty value to me

Comment: or `find / -name db_IRP_rec` and then `rm -rf /var/mysql/db_IRP_rec` that works